# Hide backbar button in navigationbar in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In my iPhone App there are three views, *firstView*, *secondView* and *thirdView*.

now I want to put Back Button  in navigation bar in *thirdView* only  which should  take me to back *secondView* only

for that i m writing this code in first view

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton:NO;
```

and it shows the back button in both the views *secondView* and *thirdView*

what I should do to hide back button in the the *secondView*?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you have to set *`[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES]`* in your *secondView*.
And set *`[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO]`* in your *thirdView*.

Comment: thanks for reply. i tried to do that and it hides the back button from secondView but the probleams is it also hides backbutton from thirdView but I want to meke backbutton visible in the thirdView

Comment: @Prerak: Set [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO] in your thirdView

Answer (score 3):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=nil;

}
OR
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

To hide the back button in the navigation bar

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}
```

To show the back button in the navigation bar

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
}
```